# Manually update carrier settings after dismissing prompt

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers

My iPhone with iOS 10 recently popped up a dialogue prompting me to update my carrier settings and I accidentally pressed not now.

Is there a way to re-open that dialogue? A button that should be pressed somewhere? A page that needs to be opened in one of my apps? I have tried opening software update, Carrier settings, Phone settings, etc., but I just can't update my carrier settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going to [Settings > General > About](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201270) should trigger a manual check for carrier settings updates.